# Python Function that Match a Given Template

Tags: python, function

Say I have a template and I have a dictionary containing words. I want to create a function that returns a list of words that **match** the given template. To illustrate this:

```
template = 'W**ER'
dictionary = {'apple': '', 'water': '', 'weber': '', 'tiger': '', 'elder': '', 'rover': '', 'waver': ''}


Desired output:
output_list = ['water', 'weber', 'waver']
```

I'm not entirely sure how to create the function and I would totally appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Does template have to be like that? I thing using regex right here is much simpler

Comment: The template can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution

```
import re

dictionary = {'apple': '', 'water': '', 'weber': '', 'tiger': '', 'elder': '', 'rover': '', 'waver': ''}
keys = list(dictionary.keys()) # not necessary but I think it's cleaner

output_list = [key for key in keys if re.search(r'^w..er$', key)]
```

First `^` assert this is the beginning of your word (prevent word that would not start with w but still have this pattern inside), `re.match` does it by default, `.` correspond to any character and `$` as for `^` assert you touch the end of the string (here, the word).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to find a matched keys with the templete.

My code find all the matched keys, and it is ***case-insensitive*** code, as follows:

```py
import re

dictionary = {'apple': '', 'water': '', 'weber': '', 'tiger': '', 'elder': '', 'rover': '', 'waver': ''}

output = []
for key in dictionary.keys():
    matched = re.match("[Ww]+..[Ee]+[Rr]+$", key) # case-insensitive, 5 letters
    if matched:
        output.append(key)

print(output)
#['water', 'weber', 'waver']
```

For more information about regular expressions with examples, you can see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: You could add a '$' at the and of the regular expression no ?

Comment: @Apo You're right, thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex:

```py
import re
ptrn = re.compile("w..er")
list(filter(lambda key: re.match(ptrn, key), dictionary))
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the answers contain '.' as any symbol, although it may be better to use any letter instead. Also note having start of string and end of string. That means that `waterdasdadad` won't proceed

Here is my code

```
import re

template = r'^w\w\wer$'  # means start of string, w, any alphabet char twice, e, r, end of string
regex = re.compile(template)
dictionary = {'apple': '', 'water': '', 'weber': '', 'tiger': '', 'elder': '', 'rover': '', 'waver': ''}

output_list = list()

for key in dictionary:
    if regex.fullmatch(key):  # use key.lower() for case insensitivity
        output_list.append(key)

print(output_list)
```